# Should I clone specific third party data, or create a generic table to handle multiple third parties?

Tags: database, database-design

Let's say I have an online store, and I integrate third party service to deal payments.

If the third party service gives API notifications to receive statuses, and those notifications come in a structured format that is consistent, such as:

```
{
    "status": "foo",
    "status_text": "bar",
    "amount": 1000,
    // ...
}
```

And I create a table in my database to represent that data, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE specific_third_party_notifications (
    status VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    status_text VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    amount VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    -- etc...
);
```

If I have a table in my app that is related to that data, would this typically be seen as a good way to handle the relationship, or should I create a more generic table that isn't bound to any third party?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE acme_notifications (
    status VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    status_text VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    amount VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    -- etc...
);
```

I ask because I am in a situation now where I have created tables specifically to represent that third party data, but one of my other tables relates to all those tables.

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to couple my app to the third party services data tightly like this, or if I should create a more generic table like the second table example, so that I'm not tightly coupled to the third party service and if I decide one day to use another one or make my own, then my schema doesn't really have to change at all, I'd be able to just remove the third party tables, add new third party tables, etc.

The only problem I see with the generic table us things like not being able to be flexible enough to have columns that work for all third party services, etc.

Would love some insight on this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.  But tying your solution too closely to third party data formats seems dangerous and brittle for a robust application.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I thought so, thanks. Just wanted to get some ideas on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend having a log table first which logs the response that you received from third party as is.
2. You can have a staging table which parses the received data into the needed format, this table should be independent and should not be linked to any app tables
3. Third table will have the needed columns and can be tightly integrated with app tables